# How to remove this special character at the end of the file

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

This is the output of `cat` command and I don't know what this special character is called that is at the end of the file to even search for. How to remove this special character in bash?
[image]

**EDIT**:

Here is the actual xml file(I am just copy pasting):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
    <members>CreditNotesManager</members>
    <members>CreditNotesManagerTest</members>
  </types>
  <version>47.0</version>
</Package>%
```

Comment: @l'L'l  When I open the file in VSCode, it is removing. I copied the character from terminal and added to the xml content.

Comment: Strange. Try in `bash` doing `sed 's/\(</.*>\)%.*/\1/g' file.xml`, and see what it does.

Comment: That won't save the file though with the change, so I'll show you how to do that.

Comment: @Jetchisel `xml` file is created by salesforce CLI. Not sure if it is internally doing something screwy to add this special character at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear how the `%` (percent sign) is ending up in your file; it's easy to remove with `sed`:

```
sed -i '' 's/\(</.*>\)%.*/\1/g' file.xml
```

This will remove the percent and re-save your file. If you want to do a dry-run omit the `-i ''` portion as this is tells `sed` to save the file in-line.

[As mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716280/how-to-remove-this-special-character-at-the-end-of-the-file/60716480#comment107424377_60716280), there are many ways to do it. Just be sure you aren't removing something that you want to keep.

Comment: I posted the same question on reddit when someone just downvoted without any feedback and they say, it is `zsh` terminal thing and this character doesn't really exist in the file : https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/fjz726/how_to_remove_special_character_that_is_displayed/

Comment: @javanoob: Interesting no doubt; definitely not downvote worthy. Mac switched which shell they use in terminal by default in version 10.15 to `zsh` and there are some major differences. I’m still using 10.14 so the behavior isn’t something i had thought of really. As the saying goes, the more you know apparently...

Answer (score 1):

If it is just at the last line, this should work. Using `ed(1)`

```
printf '%s\n' '$s/%//' w | ed -s file.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to save changes, you could use grep:

```
grep -v "%" <file.xml
```

This uses grep along with it's inverse matching flag `-v`.  This method will remove all instances of the character `%` and print the result to STOUT. The `<` character is a method to tell grep which file you're talking about.

EDIT: actually you don't even need the redirection, so:

`grep -v "%" file.xml`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a feature of zsh, not bash. 
To disable it, `unsetopt prompt_cr prompt_sp`
The reverse prompt character showing up means that line had an end-of-file before a final ascii linefeed (newline) character.
[How to remove this special character at the end of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716280/how-to-remove-this-special-character-at-the-end-of-the-file)