# Reading XML file in bash script makes the XML invalid

Tags: xml, bash, shell, curl, dymo

I'm trying to load an XML file from file in order to send it to my DYMO label printer.

The Curl command that I execute to print a label from XML file is

```bash
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/PrintLabel' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'printerName='"$printerName"'' \
--data-urlencode 'labelXml='"$labelContent"'' \
--data-urlencode 'labelSetXml=' \
--data-urlencode 'printParamsXml='
```

If I manually put the content inside labelContent (like shown below) it works and prints my label:

```bash
labelContent='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <DesktopLabel Version="1"> <DYMOLabel Version="3"> <Description>DYMO Label</Description> <Orientation>Landscape</Orientation> <LabelName>ReturnAddressInt</LabelName> <InitialLength>0</InitialLength> <BorderStyle>SolidLine</BorderStyle> <DYMORect> <DYMOPoint> <X>0.09</X> <Y>0.05666666</Y> </DYMOPoint> <Size> <Width>1.976667</Width> <Height>0.9033334</Height> </Size> </DYMORect> <BorderColor> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </BorderColor> <BorderThickness>1</BorderThickness> <Show_Border>False</Show_Border> <DynamicLayoutManager> <RotationBehavior>ClearObjects</RotationBehavior> <LabelObjects> <TextObject> <Name>MODEL</Name> <Brushes> <BackgroundBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="0" R="1" G="1" B="1"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </BackgroundBrush> <BorderBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </BorderBrush> <StrokeBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </StrokeBrush> <FillBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="0" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </FillBrush> </Brushes> <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation> <OutlineThickness>1</OutlineThickness> <IsOutlined>False</IsOutlined> <BorderStyle>SolidLine</BorderStyle> <Margin> <DYMOThickness Left="0" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0" /> </Margin> <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment> <VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment> <FitMode>None</FitMode> <IsVertical>False</IsVertical> <FormattedText> <FitMode>None</FitMode> <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment> <VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment> <IsVertical>False</IsVertical> <LineTextSpan> <TextSpan> <Text>test</Text> <FontInfo> <FontName>Helvetica</FontName> <FontSize>7.5</FontSize> <IsBold>False</IsBold> <IsItalic>False</IsItalic> <IsUnderline>False</IsUnderline> <FontBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </FontBrush> </FontInfo> </TextSpan> </LineTextSpan> </FormattedText> <ObjectLayout> <DYMOPoint> <X>0.11</X> <Y>0.6113067</Y> </DYMOPoint> <Size> <Width>1.916667</Width> <Height>0.2083333</Height> </Size> </ObjectLayout> </TextObject> </LabelObjects> </DynamicLayoutManager> </DYMOLabel> <LabelApplication>Blank</LabelApplication> <DataTable> <Columns></Columns> <Rows></Rows> </DataTable> </DesktopLabel>'
```

However loading the exact same XML from file it does not work. The entire function looks like this:

```bash
printLabel()
{
    echo "Printing $1"

    labelContent=`cat $1`

    #labelContent='COPY CONTENT OF ECHO HERE, UNCOMMENT, AND WILL WORK...'

    printerName="DYMO LabelWriter 4XL"

    # Verifying here on the output that the content of the file is ok and it looks perfect
    echo $labelContent

    curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/PrintLabel' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'printerName='"$printerName"'' \
    --data-urlencode 'labelXml='"$labelContent"'' \
    --data-urlencode 'labelSetXml=' \
    --data-urlencode 'printParamsXml='
}
```

However when loading this file from right from the file system (by executing the method like this `printLabel /Users/myusername/Documents/test.dymo` it throws me an error:

```bash
Printing labels...
Printing test.dymo
[FULL XML OUTPUT HERE]
Error printing label. Exception: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.%
```

It seems like the content that I'm reading from file is not exactly the same (maybe with the double quotes or so) which causes the XML validation to fail on it.

If I remove the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` line from the XML file I get a similar result. With manual copy/paste of the echoed XML it works, but then the error from the XML parser is slightly different:

```bash
Printing labels...
Printing test.dymo
<DesktopLabel Version="1"> <DYMOLabel Version="3"> <Description>DYMO Label</Description> <Orientation>Landscape</Orientation> <LabelName>ReturnAddressInt</LabelName> <InitialLength>0</InitialLength> <BorderStyle>SolidLine</BorderStyle> <DYMORect> <DYMOPoint> <X>0.09</X> <Y>0.05666666</Y> </DYMOPoint> <Size> <Width>1.976667</Width> <Height>0.9033334</Height> </Size> </DYMORect> <BorderColor> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </BorderColor> <BorderThickness>1</BorderThickness> <Show_Border>False</Show_Border> <DynamicLayoutManager> <RotationBehavior>ClearObjects</RotationBehavior> <LabelObjects> <TextObject> <Name>MODEL</Name> <Brushes> <BackgroundBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="0" R="1" G="1" B="1"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </BackgroundBrush> <BorderBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </BorderBrush> <StrokeBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </StrokeBrush> <FillBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="0" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </FillBrush> </Brushes> <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation> <OutlineThickness>1</OutlineThickness> <IsOutlined>False</IsOutlined> <BorderStyle>SolidLine</BorderStyle> <Margin> <DYMOThickness Left="0" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0" /> </Margin> <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment> <VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment> <FitMode>None</FitMode> <IsVertical>False</IsVertical> <FormattedText> <FitMode>None</FitMode> <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment> <VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment> <IsVertical>False</IsVertical> <LineTextSpan> <TextSpan> <Text>test</Text> <FontInfo> <FontName>Helvetica</FontName> <FontSize>7.5</FontSize> <IsBold>False</IsBold> <IsItalic>False</IsItalic> <IsUnderline>False</IsUnderline> <FontBrush> <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush> </FontBrush> </FontInfo> </TextSpan> </LineTextSpan> </FormattedText> <ObjectLayout> <DYMOPoint> <X>0.11</X> <Y>0.6113067</Y> </DYMOPoint> <Size> <Width>1.916667</Width> <Height>0.2083333</Height> </Size> </ObjectLayout> </TextObject> </LabelObjects> </DynamicLayoutManager> </DYMOLabel> <LabelApplication>Blank</LabelApplication> <DataTable> <Columns></Columns> <Rows></Rows> </DataTable> </DesktopLabel>
Error printing label. Exception: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 39.%
```

Comment: This might help: [Posting XML with Curl](https://reqbin.com/req/c-yzrfjhug/curl-post-xml-example)

Comment: @Cyrus thanks for the tip but that does not really help since that is about posting XML in the body. I actually can post the XML in my data url-encoded property as part fom the www-form-urlencoded body, just not when reading it from a file in my bash script

Comment: I'd check for invisible characters in the file.  Run `cat -v FILENAME`.  Things to look out for include a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start or a carriage return (CR) character (displayed by `cat -v` as `^M`) at the end.

Comment: There are a few minor issues with the code extracts, though I don't think they are likely to be causing your problem.  Backticks were superseded by `$(...)` decades ago.  `$(cat $1)` doesn't work in general.  Use `$(cat -- "$1")` or `$(< "$1")` (the latter is a Bashism).  `echo $var` doesn't work in general.  Neither does `echo "$var"` (though it works more often).  Use `printf '%s\n' "$var"`.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)  can find problems in shell code.

Comment: @pjh Thanks for you answers, the `cat -v filename` does not show me any other characters other than a '%' at the end of the file. No clue what that means...
For the optimisations of the script, that does indeed make sense, however does not change the result (as expected) of the curl-call...

Comment: There shouldn't be a `%` at the end of the file.  I'd try re-creating the file by saving directly from a known-good variable: `labelContent='<?xml ... </DesktopLabel>'; printf '%s\n' "$labelContent" >FILENAME`.  If you've still got a `%` at the end of the `cat -v FILENAME` output after that you've got something *really* weird going  on.

Comment: Possible explanation: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739298](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739298 "How to remove this special character at the end of the file"), cf. [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol/302710](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol/302710#302710).

Answer (score 0):

This may sound too simplistic, but ...

Have you tried replacing

```
--data-urlencode 'labelXml='"$labelContent"''
```

with

```
--data-urlencode "labelXml='$labelContent'"
```

Comment: No that gives me exactly the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the alternate approach that is incorporated in this demo script, changing

```
--data-urlencode 'labelXml='"${labelContent}"''
```

to

```
--data-urlencode "labelXml@${labelContentFile}"
```

I've also reformatted your one-liner for easier viewing.

```
#!/bin/bash

labelContentFile="testInput.xml"

cat >${labelContentFile} <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DesktopLabel Version="1">
<DYMOLabel Version="3">
    <Description>DYMO Label</Description>
    <Orientation>Landscape</Orientation>
    <LabelName>ReturnAddressInt</LabelName>
    <InitialLength>0</InitialLength>
    <BorderStyle>SolidLine</BorderStyle>
    <DYMORect>
        <DYMOPoint> <X>0.09</X> <Y>0.05666666</Y> </DYMOPoint>
        <Size>
            <Width>1.976667</Width>
            <Height>0.9033334</Height>
        </Size>
    </DYMORect>
    <BorderColor>
        <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush>
    </BorderColor>
    <BorderThickness>1</BorderThickness>
    <Show_Border>False</Show_Border>
    <DynamicLayoutManager>
        <RotationBehavior>ClearObjects</RotationBehavior>
        <LabelObjects>
            <TextObject>
                <Name>MODEL</Name>
                <Brushes>
                    <BackgroundBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="0" R="1" G="1" B="1"></Color> </SolidColorBrush>
                    </BackgroundBrush>
                    <BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush>
                    </BorderBrush>
                    <StrokeBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush>
                    </StrokeBrush>
                    <FillBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="0" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush>
                    </FillBrush>
                </Brushes>
                <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>
                <OutlineThickness>1</OutlineThickness>
                <IsOutlined>False</IsOutlined>
                <BorderStyle>SolidLine</BorderStyle>
                <Margin>
                    <DYMOThickness Left="0" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0" />
                </Margin>
                <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>
                <VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment>
                <FitMode>None</FitMode>
                <IsVertical>False</IsVertical>
                <FormattedText>
                    <FitMode>None</FitMode>
                    <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>
                    <VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment>
                    <IsVertical>False</IsVertical>
                    <LineTextSpan>
                        <TextSpan>
                            <Text>test</Text>
                            <FontInfo>
                                <FontName>Helvetica</FontName>
                                <FontSize>7.5</FontSize>
                                <IsBold>False</IsBold>
                                <IsItalic>False</IsItalic>
                                <IsUnderline>False</IsUnderline>
                                <FontBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush> <Color A="1" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color> </SolidColorBrush>
                                </FontBrush>
                            </FontInfo>
                        </TextSpan>
                    </LineTextSpan>
                </FormattedText>
                <ObjectLayout>
                    <DYMOPoint> <X>0.11</X> <Y>0.6113067</Y> </DYMOPoint>
                    <Size>
                        <Width>1.916667</Width>
                        <Height>0.2083333</Height>
                    </Size>
                </ObjectLayout>
            </TextObject>
        </LabelObjects>
    </DynamicLayoutManager>
</DYMOLabel>
<LabelApplication>Blank</LabelApplication>
<DataTable>
    <Columns></Columns>
    <Rows></Rows>
</DataTable>
</DesktopLabel>
EnDoFiNpUt


original()
{
    labelContent=$( cat "${labelContentFile}" )

    curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/PrintLabel' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'printerName='"${printerName}"'' \
    --data-urlencode 'labelXml='"${labelContent}"'' \
    --data-urlencode 'labelSetXml=' \
    --data-urlencode 'printParamsXml='
}
#original

revised()
{
    curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/PrintLabel' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'printerName='"${printerName}"'' \
    --data-urlencode "labelXml@${labelContentFile}" \
    --data-urlencode 'labelSetXml=' \
    --data-urlencode 'printParamsXml='
}
revised
```

Comment: In this case I'm getting a `Invalid form collection, verify the parameters.%`

Comment: After reading the curl man page, I would suggest trying just ... **--data-urlencode labelXml@${labelContentFile}** ... or simply ... **--data-urlencode labelXml="${labelContent}"**